# what is NN type for finding image average color (RGB)

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want tarin ANN for finding the average `RGB` of `.jpg` Image?

I can't classify this problem. in my opinion it's not a `classification` problem, because I don't have any classes / labels to compere with, and it's not a `segmentation` problem, because I don't want to find any "area" or "class" in an image. what kind of a problem it is?

In my opinion the input should be an `.jpg` image and ground-truth `.png` image with the average `RGB`. the output should be 3 neurons (Red, Green and Blue average colors of an Image), and the loss layer should be linear type, because the `RGB` is in range of `0-255`. I would appreciate your help. thanks.

**Update:**

after checking and training few variations of NN my conclusion is that this is not `Regression` problem. i'll try the `full conv net` with dataset made of - colorized images and their original version as ground-truth image

Comment: Why do you need a NN to do this? Can't you just compute the average color on your input image?

Comment: NN - (Artificial) neural network. my goal is making a NN that will be able to recognize the average RGB of each image.

Comment: Ok, but... there's nothing to actually _recognize_, since you can compute it exactly. Am I missing something?

Comment: you right in some point. let's say that my input (test image) was colorized with some color (RGB), so I want that this net will be able to find the average RGB to compute this values with the original image RGB values.

Comment: This is just a regression problem.

Comment: thank you @MatiasValdenegro !!! do you have any suggestions or tips for  architecture of my purpose net?

Comment: @Z.Kal I could not relate 0-255 and linear loss. However, I also think that your system must be linear, because the averaging is simple and linear problem.

Comment: You can simply do AVG pool with global_pool and get the mean color

Comment: @Shai my goal is learn NN to solve this problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro after train and check NN (prob) results, my conclusion is that this is not "Regression" problem. i'll try another way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the trick here is to store the training labels: three float labels per input image. The most straight forward way (IMHO) is to use `"HDF5Data"` layer to store both images and RGB target labels. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31808324/1714410) for an example.

Once you have the data, you can have this simple net

```
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "bgr_label"
  # ...
}
layer {
  name: "fc"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "bgr_mean"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3 # predict BGR values
    bias_term: 0  # do not subtract mean, no need for bias in this task
    weight_filler { type: "constant" value: 1.5e-5 } # set the value to 1/num_pixels
  }
  # ... set learning rate and regularization multipliers
}
layer {
  name: "loss" 
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  bottom: "bgr_mean"
  bottom: "bgr_label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: thanks. can you please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280068/float-multi-label-regression-in-caffe-loss-results

about `EuclideanLoss `

Comment: what do you mean when you write "set `learning rate` and `regularization multipliers`"? you mean `weight_decay` or another layers? thanks

Comment: @Z.Kal I mean setting `lr_mult` and `decay_mult` parameters

Comment: so should I add `conv` layers with `lr_mult` and `decay_mult` before the `InnerProduct ` layer?

Comment: @Z.Kal no `conv` layers! you do not need `conv` for this task. only `"InnerProduct"`.

Comment: so where and how should I set learning rate and regularization multipliers?

Comment: this is my `fc` layer (with `weight_decay`):

`layers {
  name: "fc6"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "data"
  top: "fc6"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
      variance_norm: AVERAGE
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}`

but the the loss now is even more huge:

`Iteration 0, loss = 57772.5 Iteration 400, loss = nan`

Comment: do you have any idea how to reduce the loss rate? thanks

Comment: @Z.Kal I am sorry, but I do not understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I have prepared the data set and implemented NN as you said, it works! but the loss is very high (`Iteration 0, loss = 57772.5 Iteration 400, loss = nan`). are you sure your net architecture is good  enough for my problem?

Comment: after checking and training few variations of NN my conclusion is that this is not "Regression" problem. i'll try the full conv net with dataset made of - colorized images and their original version as ground-truth image